# PHP + Mysql: Return function only show last result

Tags: php, mysql, return

I'm editing file php for telegram bot. When I test on telegram, it only show just last value (but on php command line, there are more than one value) for this code:

```php
if (mysqli_num_rows($cari) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cari)) {
        $hasil = "QS.[".$row["surat"]."-" . $row["nosurat"]. "]:" . $row["ayat"]. ": " . $row["ayattext"]. ". ";
        var_dump($hasil);
    } 
} else {
    $hasil = "0 results";
}
return $hasil;
mysqli_close($conn);
```

When I change function create_response to this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($cari) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cari)) {
    $hasil = "QS.[".$row["surat"]."-" . $row["nosurat"]. "]:" . $row["ayat"]. ": " . $row["ayattext"]. ". ";
    var_dump($hasil);
} 
} else {
$hasil = "0 results";
}
return $hasil;
mysqli_close($conn);
```

It works, but it only show just last value on telegram. But on php command line show complete result as I want.

How to fix this problem? Thanks before...

Here's the complete code:

```
<?php
include("token.php");
//include("db.php");

function request_url($method)
{
    global $TOKEN;
    return "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $TOKEN . "/". $method;
}

function get_updates($offset) 
{
    $url = request_url("getUpdates")."?offset=".$offset;
        $resp = file_get_contents($url);
        $result = json_decode($resp, true);
        if ($result["ok"]==1)
            return $result["result"];
        return array();
}

function send_reply($chatid, $msgid, $text)
{
    $data = array(
        'chat_id' => $chatid,
        'text'  => $text,
        'reply_to_message_id' => $msgid

    );
    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);

    $result = file_get_contents(request_url('sendMessage'), false, $context);
    print_r($result);
}

function create_response($text)
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxx","aq");
    $data = array();
    $sql = "Select s.text_sr AS surat, s.no_sr AS nosurat, qi.verseid AS ayat, qi.ayahtext AS ayattext from quranindonesia qi left join surah s on qi.suraid=s.no_sr where qi.ayahtext like '%$text%' limit 3,5";
    $cari = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    //$hasil = '';

    if (mysqli_num_rows($cari) > 0) {
        $hasil = array();
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cari)) {
            $hasil[] = "QS.[".$row["surat"]."-" . $row["nosurat"]. "]:" . $row["ayat"]. ": " . $row["ayattext"]. ". ";
            //var_dump($hasil);
        } 
        } else {
        $hasil = "0 results";
        }
        return $hasil;
        mysqli_close($conn);
}



function process_message($message)
{
    $updateid = $message["update_id"];
    $message_data = $message["message"];
    if (isset($message_data["text"])) {
    $chatid = $message_data["chat"]["id"];
        $message_id = $message_data["message_id"];
        $text = $message_data["text"];
        $response = create_response($text);
        send_reply($chatid, $message_id, $response);
    }
    return $updateid;
}


function process_one()
{
    $update_id  = 0;

    if (file_exists("last_update_id")) {
        $update_id = (int)file_get_contents("last_update_id");
    }

    $updates = get_updates($update_id);

    foreach ($updates as $message)
    {
            $update_id = process_message($message);
    }
    file_put_contents("last_update_id", $update_id + 1);

}

while (true) {
    process_one();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A return statement always returns exactly one argument. That is how it works. If you need all rows you will have to put them into an array and return that. This is a simple demonstration:

```
<?php
function returnRows($cari) {
    $hasil = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cari)) {
        $hasil[] = sprintf(
            "QS.[%s-%s]:%s: %s. ",
            $row["surat"], 
            $row["nosurat"], 
            $row["ayat"], 
            $row["ayattext"]
        );
    } 
    return $hasil;
}
```

That will return an array, each element of the array holds a string as you concatenated it in the assignment.

Comment: Already tried this way, but i try again as your suggest. But there's no result at all and in php command line show this error: Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage): failed to
open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 in G:\xampp\htdocs\xbot\file.php on line 39

Comment: And this is what in line 39:
$result = file_get_contents(request_url('sendMessage'), false, $context);

Comment: It might well be that you get another error. But I do not see any connection with the code above _at all_. That code line certainly is not part of the function you asked your question about. Can't say anything about code you did not post here, sorry.

Comment: Arghh too long to post in here.

Comment: Please post only cleaned up, shortened code, just enough to demonstrate your issue. Never post _all_ your code. And always include _all_ additional information in the question itself (there is an `edit` button), do not post additional information to comments.

Comment: Sorry for edit and posting complete code because i don't have any ideas what's goin on.

Comment: Well obviously the error messages shows that the result of `request_url('sendMessage')` is not a url that references a service you can call like that. HTTP code 400 means that the server got your request, but refuses to reply, since your request was wrong. Most likely you miss authorization to access the service or there are arguments missing in your request. HOWEVER: this appears to be a totally separate thing. It has nothing to do with your original question. Please ask separate issues in separate questions. So open a new question for that. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @arckascha, I've open new question for that. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493684/php-mysql-return-function-only-show-last-result

Again, thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0):

You can to use an array, like this:

```
$linesArr = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($cari) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cari)) {
        $linesArr[] = "QS.[".$row["surat"]."-" . $row["nosurat"]. "]:" . $row["ayat"]. ": " . $row["ayattext"];
    } 
    $hasil = implode(", ", $linesArr) . ".";
} else {
    $hasil = "0 results";
}
return $hasil;
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Already tried this way, but i try again as your suggest. But there's no result at all and in php command line show this error: Warning: file_get_contents(api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in G:\xampp\htdocs\xbot\file.php on line 39

Comment: And this is what in line 39: $result = file_get_contents(request_url('sendMessage'), false, $context);

Comment: The problem you described above has nothing to do with the problem described in your question. In that case, I suggest you open another question and explain that other problem. Certainly, someone will help you with that. This one has already been addressed by me and @arkascha.

Comment: Thank you Marcos and @arckascha. I'd edit and post complete code.